# Avoid Duplicate Literals Sonar Error

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube to verify and inspect my Java code, and i've encountered an issue with  Avoid Duplicate Literals in an Enum class type, here is an exemple :

```
public enum Products {

  A ("Product A"),
  C ("Product A"),
  D ("Product B"),
  P ("Product B");

  private String name = "";

  Products (String name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String toString(){
    return name;
  }
}
```

Sonar is telling me to declare the Strings 'Product A' and 'Product B' as a constant field, but you can't declare variables in Enum type class.

Comment: If sonar is telling you that its wrong to duplicate a small single string, then you should probably just turn off sonar because it's wasting your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the constant outside of the enum:

```
private static final String TYPE_A_NAME = "Type A";

public enum Type {

    TYPEA(TYPE_A_NAME), TYPEB("B");

    private String value;

    Type(String value) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Create Prefix (private static final Sting PREFIX = Product.class.getSimpleName()+ "."

and A("A"), etc...

you return a string, you can use a MessageFormatter to internationalize your string in a properties file

Product.A=Product A, etc...

and the constructor is private

you can make a getter like

`

`public static String getI18NString(String key){
       return Internationalizer.getI18String(PREFIX + key);
}`

public class Internationalizer {
    /** The logger of this class. */
    private static final Log                   LOGGER                      = LogFactory.getLog(Internationalizer.class);

```
/** */
private static ResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();

/**
 * Get the internationalized String form properties files
 *
 * @param key
 * @return
 */
public static String getI18String(final String key) {
    String message = "";
    try {
        message = resourceBundleMessageSource.getMessage(key, null, Locale.getDefault());
    } catch (NoSuchMessageException e) {
        LOGGER.info("Key not internationalized : " + key);
        message = key;
    }
    return message;
}

/**
 * Set the bundles for internationalization Injected by Spring
 *
 * @param bundles
 */
public void setBundles(final List<String> bundles) {
    String[] bundlesArrays = new String[bundles.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < bundles.size(); i++) {
        bundlesArrays[i] = bundles.get(i);
    }
    resourceBundleMessageSource.setBasenames(bundlesArrays);
}
```

}

`